# How can i disable specific days dynamically in datepicker?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

How can i disable specific days dynamically , For that I am using this code :-

```
<div id="disableVal_12">1,2</div>

<script>
    var daysToDisable = [$("#disableVal_12").html()];
    $('#datepickerPospond_2').datepicker({
        firstDay:1,
        beforeShowDay: disableSpecificWeekDays
    });
    function setDateZero(date){
        return date < 10 ? '0' + date : date;
    }
    function disableSpecificWeekDays(date) {

        var day = date.getDay();
        var m = date.getMonth(), d = date.getDate(), y = date.getFullYear();
        var date = setDateZero(d) + '/' + setDateZero((m+1)) + '/' + y;
        for (i = 0; i < daysToDisable.length; i++) {
            if ($.inArray(day, daysToDisable) == -1) {
                return [false];
            }else if ($.inArray(date , datesToDisable) == 1) {
                return [false];
            }
        }
        return [true];
    }
</script>
```

If any one have any better solution please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

EXAMPLE CODE:

```
var unavailableDates = ["9-5-2011","14-5-2011","15-5-2011"];

function unavailable(date) {
  dmy = date.getDate() + "-" + (date.getMonth()+1) + "-" + date.getFullYear();
  if ($.inArray(dmy, unavailableDates) < 0) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}

$('#iDate').datepicker({ beforeShowDay: unavailable });
```

[**SEE HERE**](http://tokenposts.blogspot.in/2011/05/jquery-datepicker-disable-specific.html) and [**HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/6SyfY/)

Comment: Thanks PSR for the support But i want "unavailableDates" dynamic. I don't want this static , So could you give me an example for that .

Comment: Then Create an array and then get the dates dynamically and push into that array